# Confusing outcome of C conditional operator

Tags: c++, c, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

```
int a=1,b=2,c=3;
int x=1;
int y=10;
a = x ? b : c;  
cout<< a;      // Outputs 2 (the value of b)
a = y ? b : c; 
cout<< a;      // Outputs 2 (the value of b)
```

Now, look at the following.

```
a=0;
x=0;
a = x ? b : c;
cout<< a;  //   Outputs 3 (the value of c !!!!)
```

Why this unusual behaviour ?? Only when a and x are both 0, the expression evaluates to *false* , otherwise, always it is *true*. Please explain.

Comment: Uhm... the behavior is quite usual in fact. And you are not reading the results of your experiment correctly if your conclusion is that *both* `a` and `x` must be `0` for `a` to acquire the value of `c`

Comment: Yes. I get it now. I concluded it wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `x` is 0.

Recall that the ternary operator, if written `condition ? a : b` returns `a` if `condition` is true and `b` otherwise. You are using it with numbers, and any number except 0 is considered `true` as a boolean.

`x ? b : c` in your case is `0 ? 2 : 3`, and since `0` is `false`, it evaluates to 3. That 3 then gets assigned to your `a` variable and printed - nothing unusual going on here.

Answer (score 4):

This looks perfectly fine. The expression `a = x ? b : c` is equivalent to

```
if (x)
    a = b;
else
    a = c;
```

x will evaluate to true for any nonzero value, so if you assign 0 to x prior to executing the expression, the value of c will be assigned to a, and if you assign 1 to x prior to executing the expression, the value of b will be assigned to a. The prior value of a is immaterial here.

Comment: On assigning `0` to `x` how `b` will be assign to `a`?

Comment: @hhacks, I updated the answer to make the wording more clear. Of course nothing happens to a if you assign a value to x; what I meant is that if x has the value 0 when the statement is executed, then a will get the value of b, and otherwise, a will get the value of c.

Comment: @KristianDuske;  If `x` has the value `0` when the statement is executed, then `a` will get the value of `c` not  `b`! because `0` stands for false.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that in C and C++ *any* non-zero value is evaluated as "true".

Answer (score 0):

The value of 'a' only depends on the value of 'x' and 'y'. Since initially 'x' and 'y' are both greater than 0, the condition evaluates to true and you get the value of 'b' in 'a'.
In the second case, 'x' is zero which evaluates the condition to false which causes 'a' to have the value of 'c'.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = x ? b : c;
```

is the same as

```
if(x != 0) {
    a = b;
} else {
    a = c;
}
```

Therefore if you set x = 0 you will get a = c.